# How can I set a range equal to variable values?

Tags: excel, vba

Here I define the worksheet CCCE to receive variable values:

```
For Each wb In Workbooks
   
    If InStr(wb.Name, "Compeat US Bank Upload") Then
       Set wbut = wb  'ut = upload template
       Set CCCE = wbut.Sheets("Corner CC Entries")
       ClearTargetSheet
       Exit For
    End If
Next wb
```

In this subroutine, I load values into the variables Account, Entity and Amt, and they are stored in that order in the variables, but the commented-out portion with 3 CCCE.Range commands errors-out.  I thought that .value would work when .Address did not, but neither approach worked.

```
Public Sub Process()

Dim a, ColA As Range, Account, lastrowA, Entity As String, Ent As String, Amt As Double, ctr 
As Integer
lastrowA = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

FindPivot

Set ColA = ws.Range(Cells(fprow + 1, 1).Address, Cells(lastrowA - 1, 1).Address)

ctr = 4

'Find pivot values amd store them in variables
For Each a In ColA
    If InStr(a.Value, "#") > 0 Then
           Ent = a.Value
           If Ent = "#3 Ann Arbor" Then
              Entity = "003"
           ElseIf Ent = "#5 Plymouth" Then
              Entity = "005"
           End If
       
           Amt = a.Offset(0, 1) * -1
       
           ctr = ctr + 1
           'CCCE.Range(Cells(ctr, 1).value = Account
           'CCCE.Range(Cells(ctr, 2).Address = Entity
           'CCCE.Range(Cells(ctr, 3).Address = Amt
                  
                   
    ElseIf a.Value > 1000 Then
           Account = a.Value
       
   
    End If
      'Exit For

Next


End Sub
```

Many thanks for assistance with my project.

Brian

Comment: "errors-out" - what is the exact error message you're getting?  Those 3 lines are all missing a closing `)` but the syntax is off.    `CCCE.Range(Cells(ctr, 1).value = Account` should be `CCCE.Cells(ctr, 1).value = Account` and similar for the other 2 lines

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for the correct syntax!  Dropping "Range" was the key point for me. I did see the missing closing ) but had sent my question already.